# How to write the letter ñ in textbuffer gtkmmTextView?

Tags: c++, utf-8, textview, gtkmm

When I try to insert the ñ in textbuffer TextView the CMD displays the following error:

> (textEditor.exe:696): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_text_buffer_emit_insert: assertion
>   g_utf8_validate (text, len, NULL)'
>   failed

Source example (c++ and gtkmm):

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TextBuffer> refTextBuffer = textView->get_buffer();
refTextBuffer->set_text("\xA4");            //hex ASCII
refTextBuffer->insert_at_cursor("ñ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wanting a UTF-8 value and you've selected something in the upper ASCII range that doesn't map to UFT-8. Looking [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%C3%B1) and then [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f1/index.htm) it appears you need to use the value of `0xC3 0xB1` to get the desired affect. A quick guess for the code that should work for you is...

```
refTextBuffer->set_text("\xC3\xB1"); //Hex version of UTF-8 Value
```